# basic addition as per the below fasion

Tags: r

i have to calculate the marks in the below fashion.

```
ITEMS                   A   B   C   E   F   G   H   I   J   K
COLLECTION              10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
FINAL CALCULATION           10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90
```

Here for A there are 10 items collection for the first round its final calculation will be blank, for B - its collection is 10 so final calc will be 10, but then for C - its previous final calc and the present collection. so C = 10 + final cal of B = 10 + 10 = 20

Same with D, 10 + 20 =30, D = 30.

collection can change randomly, its just a row that should be considered in df.

```
dput(df)
structure(list(X = structure(2:1, .Label = c("collection", "item"
), class = "factor"), V1 = structure(2:1, .Label = c("10", "A"
), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(2:1, .Label = c("20", "A"
), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(2:1, .Label = c("10", "A"
), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(2:1, .Label = c("20", "A"
), class = "factor"), V5 = structure(2:1, .Label = c("10", "A"
), class = "factor"), V6 = structure(2:1, .Label = c("20", "A"
), class = "factor"), V7 = structure(2:1, .Label = c("10", "A"
), class = "factor"), V8 = structure(2:1, .Label = c("10", "A"
), class = "factor"), V9 = structure(2:1, .Label = c("20", "A"
), class = "factor"), V10 = structure(2:1, .Label = c("20", "A"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

my code : 
df <- data.frame(df)
df[2, ] <- c(NA, cumsum(unlist(df[1, 1:(ncol(df)-1)])))


Error: 
df[2, ] <- c(NA, cumsum(unlist(df[1, 1:(ncol(df)-1)])))
Error in Math.factor(unlist(df[1, 1:(ncol(df) - 1)])) :     
  ‘cumsum’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: Try `cumsum()`. Type `?cumsum` in the console for details.

Comment: Your data structure (a) is really bad for this type of calculations, as your columns include both numbers and strings, (b) doesn't match the example you provided on top. I'll provide an answer that will work based on the structure you provided...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# update columns to character
df = sapply(df, as.character)

# set as dataframe and keep the character columns values
df = data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = F)

# add the new row at the bottom (using values from last row)
df[nrow(df)+1, ] <- as.character(c("FINAL CALCULATION", NA, cumsum(as.numeric(unlist(df[nrow(df), nrow(df):(ncol(df)-1)])))))

# view updated dataset
df

#                   X   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7  V8  V9 V10
# 1              item    A  A  A  A  A  A  A   A   A   A
# 2        collection   10 20 10 20 10 20 10  10  20  20
# 3 FINAL CALCULATION <NA> 10 30 40 60 70 90 100 110 130
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right what you look for is a cumulative sum, but for first value there shall be a na.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(rep(10, 10), ncol= 10))

df[2, ] <- c(NA, cumsum(unlist(df[1, 1:(ncol(df)-1)])))
```

EDIT

I does not have to be rep(10, 10). See here

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10, 5), ncol= 5))
df[2, ] <- c(NA, cumsum(unlist(df[1, 1:(ncol(df)-1)])))
df
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  3  4  5  7  2
2 NA  3  7 12 19
```

Comment: here collection column will not have the same items, it can be different numbers so cannot use rep(10,10)

Comment: @Prad You can just insert whatever data you have instead. It does not have to be 10 times 10. I just used your example. See my edit in the answer

Comment: please check the structure i have done dput of my df, and i am getting the error.

Comment: @schwantke what version of R are you using? If I set seed to 1, `df` values result in `c(1, 9, 4, 7, 1, 2)`

Comment: @PavoDive please check the structure of my df, i did dput

Comment: That explains it. It's using #R version 3.3.2. Random number generator's algorithm changed in 3.6: https://twitter.com/JorisMeys/status/1103589492978532352